# Why does huggingface tokenizer return only 1 `input_ids` instead of 3?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, tokenize, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to tokenize the `squad` dataset following the [huggingface tutorial](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter1/1):

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer
from transformers import logging
logging.set_verbosity_error()

dataset = load_dataset('squad')
checkpoint = 'roberta-base'
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

def tokenize_function(example):
    return tokenizer(example['question'], example['context'], [d['text'][0] for d in example['answers']], truncation=True) 

tokenized_datasets = dataset['train'].map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
```

But when I print

```
tokenized_datasets
```

I get

```
Dataset({
    features: ['id', 'title', 'context', 'question', 'answers', 'input_ids', 'attention_mask'],
    num_rows: 87599
})
```

But shouldn't this return 3 `input_ids`, one for the question one for the context and one for the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that line of code:

```py
tokenizer(example['question'], example['context'], [d['text'][0] for d in example['answers']], truncation=True)
```

shown in the course?

A Tokenizer accepts plenty of parameters with its `__call__` method ([documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__)). Since you have only specified `truncation` by its name, the other parameter values are determined by their position. That means, you are executing:

```py
tokenizer(text=example['question'], text_pair=example['context'], add_special_tokens=[d['text'][0] for d in example['answers']], truncation=True)
```

After you execute your code the sample with the `id` `5733be284776f41900661182` becomes:

```
{'id': '5733be284776f41900661182', 
'title': 'University_of_Notre_Dame', 
'context': 'Architecturally, the school has a Catholic character. Atop the Main Building\'s gold dome is a golden statue of the Virgin Mary. Immediately in front of the Main Building and facing it, is a copper statue of Christ with arms upraised with the legend "Venite Ad Me Omnes". Next to the Main Building is the Basilica of the Sacred Heart. Immediately behind the basilica is the Grotto, a Marian place of prayer and reflection. It is a replica of the grotto at Lourdes, France where the Virgin Mary reputedly appeared to Saint Bernadette Soubirous in 1858. At the end of the main drive (and in a direct line that connects through 3 statues and the Gold Dome), is a simple, modern stone statue of Mary.', 
'question': 'To whom did the Virgin Mary allegedly appear in 1858 in Lourdes France?', 
'answers': {'text': ['Saint Bernadette Soubirous'], 'answer_start': [515]}, 
'input_ids': [0, 3972, 2661, 222, 5, 9880, 2708, 2346, 2082, 11, 504, 4432, 11, 226, 2126, 10067, 1470, 116, 2, 2, 37848, 37471, 28108, 6, 5, 334, 34, 10, 4019, 2048, 4, 497, 1517, 5, 4326, 6919, 18, 1637, 31346, 16, 10, 9030, 9577, 9, 5, 9880, 2708, 4, 29261, 11, 760, 9, 5, 4326, 6919, 8, 2114, 24, 6, 16, 10, 7621, 9577, 9, 4845, 19, 3701, 62, 33161, 19, 5, 7875, 22, 39043, 1459, 1614, 1464, 13292, 4977, 845, 4130, 7, 5, 4326, 6919, 16, 5, 26429, 2426, 9, 5, 25095, 6924, 4, 29261, 639, 5, 32394, 2426, 16, 5, 7461, 26187, 6, 10, 19035, 317, 9, 9621, 8, 12456, 4, 85, 16, 10, 24633, 9, 5, 11491, 26187, 23, 226, 2126, 10067, 6, 1470, 147, 5, 9880, 2708, 2851, 13735, 352, 1382, 7, 6130, 6552, 625, 3398, 208, 22895, 853, 1827, 11, 504, 4432, 4, 497, 5, 253, 9, 5, 1049, 1305, 36, 463, 11, 10, 2228, 516, 14, 15230, 149, 155, 19638, 8, 5, 2610, 25336, 238, 16, 10, 2007, 6, 2297, 7326, 9577, 9, 2708, 4, 2], 
'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

The `input_ids` are the concatenation of `text` and `text_pair`:

```py
tokenizer.decode([0, 3972, 2661, 222, 5, 9880, 2708, 2346, 2082, 11, 504, 4432, 11, 226, 2126, 10067, 1470, 116, 2, 2, 37848, 37471, 28108, 6, 5, 334, 34, 10, 4019, 2048, 4, 497, 1517, 5, 4326, 6919, 18, 1637, 31346, 16, 10, 9030, 9577, 9, 5, 9880, 2708, 4, 29261, 11, 760, 9, 5, 4326, 6919, 8, 2114, 24, 6, 16, 10, 7621, 9577, 9, 4845, 19, 3701, 62, 33161, 19, 5, 7875, 22, 39043, 1459, 1614, 1464, 13292, 4977, 845, 4130, 7, 5, 4326, 6919, 16, 5, 26429, 2426, 9, 5, 25095, 6924, 4, 29261, 639, 5, 32394, 2426, 16, 5, 7461, 26187, 6, 10, 19035, 317, 9, 9621, 8, 12456, 4, 85, 16, 10, 24633, 9, 5, 11491, 26187, 23, 226, 2126, 10067, 6, 1470, 147, 5, 9880, 2708, 2851, 13735, 352, 1382, 7, 6130, 6552, 625, 3398, 208, 22895, 853, 1827, 11, 504, 4432, 4, 497, 5, 253, 9, 5, 1049, 1305, 36, 463, 11, 10, 2228, 516, 14, 15230, 149, 155, 19638, 8, 5, 2610, 25336, 238, 16, 10, 2007, 6, 2297, 7326, 9577, 9, 2708, 4, 2])
```

Output:

```py
<s>To whom did the Virgin Mary allegedly appear in 1858 in Lourdes France?</s></s>Architecturally, the school has a Catholic character. Atop the Main Building's gold dome is a golden statue of the Virgin Mary. Immediately in front of the Main Building and facing it, is a copper statue of Christ with arms upraised with the legend "Venite Ad Me Omnes". Next to the Main Building is the Basilica of the Sacred Heart. Immediately behind the basilica is the Grotto, a Marian place of prayer and reflection. It is a replica of the grotto at Lourdes, France where the Virgin Mary reputedly appeared to Saint Bernadette Soubirous in 1858. At the end of the main drive (and in a direct line that connects through 3 statues and the Gold Dome), is a simple, modern stone statue of Mary.</s>
```

That is a common approach to handling extractive questions-answering tasks. In this, the answers are not seen as input but are only needed as a target (i.e. predicting start and end position).

Edit:
The OP specified the question in the comments and wants to know how the input_ids of the three text entities: question, context, and answer can be returned. All that needs to be changed is that the `tokenize_function` encodes the entities independently and returns a dict:

```py
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer

dataset = load_dataset('squad')
checkpoint = 'roberta-base'
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

def tokenize_function(example):
    question_o = tokenizer(example['question'], truncation=True)
    context_o = tokenizer(example['context'], truncation=True)
    answer_o = tokenizer([d['text'][0] for d in example['answers']], truncation=True)

    return {"question_input_ids": question_o.input_ids, "question_attention_mask": question_o.attention_mask, "context_input_ids": context_o.input_ids, "context_attention_mask": context_o.attention_mask, "answer_input_ids": answer_o.input_ids, "answer_attention_mask": answer_o.attention_mask}

tokenized_datasets = dataset['train'].map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
```

Comment: Oh I get it now! Is there a way to do it correctly then? That is, to take those 3 inputs into 1 tokenizer to return 3 ids? Or do I need to have 3 tokenizers? The documentation did not mention it

Comment: @Penguin I have added a code sample.